# '<' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'function'

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, knn

Following google developers ML recipes on youtube I wrote this code and tried to run using jupyter python3 notebook.Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoeEHqVSNOw

I am not able to get result because I am getting this error **'<' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'function'**

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

def euc(a,b):
    return distance.euclidean

class KNN():
    def fit(self,X_train,y_train):
        self.X_train=X_train
        self.y_train=y_train

    def predict(self,X_test):
        predictions=[]
        for row in X_test:
            label=self.closest(row)
            predictions.append(label)
        return predictions
    def closest(self,row):
        best_dist=euc(row, self.X_train[0])
        best_index=0
        for i in range(1,len(self.X_train)):
            dist=euc(row,self.X_train[i])
            if (dist < best_dist): # <--error here
                best_dist=dist
                best_index=i
        return self.y_train[best_index]
#KNeighbors Classifier
my_classifier=KNN()
my_classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)
predictions=my_classifier.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print(accuracy_score(y_test,predictions))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def euc(a,b):
    return distance.euclidean
```

Your function `euc` is retuning a reference to the *function* `distance.euclidean`.

You instead want to *call* it:

```
def euc(a,b):
    return distance.euclidean(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that in Python one function can't be greater than another – which makes sense! You need some values to compare to see if one is greater.

In your function `euc()` you're just returning the `distance.euclidean` function rather than calling it with `a` and `b` and returning the results.

If you update `euc()` to call the function like this:

```
def euc(a, b):
    return distance.euclidean(a, b)
```

It should work A-OK.